# Ajax POST request on same php page is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

I want to send javascript variable to php on same page using ajax's POST request. i am not getting any errors but also nothing is happening.

```
<?php
// check if post 'name' request is created or not.
if (isset($_POST['name'])) { 
    echo "<script> console.log('name is " . $_POST['name'] . "') </script> ";
    exit;
}
?>

<html>

<body>
    // clickme button
    <button id="clickme"> click me! </button>

    // load ajax/jquery
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // click event listner for clickme button.
        $('#clickme').click(function () {
            // this is the variable i want to send.
            var name = 'abc';

            // ajax code.

            $.ajax({
            url: 'abc.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {name: name},
            success: function (response) {
                // Code
            }
            });
       });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to add url of same page in ajax post. but it is also not working.

Comment: What happens with this code? Does it send a request, do you get a response?